# Why Eclipse Pydev Hierarchy view doesn't work?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using PyDev to navigate the code of a relatively large Python projects. I want to view the hierarchy graph of the classes. I hit f4 to open the Hierarchy View.

But the view is completely empty, and there is nothing in it. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it here and it worked for me... To give an example:

Say you have:

```
class ClassA(object):
    pass

class ClassB(ClassA):
    pass
```

Now, with the cursor over 'ClassB' press 'F4': the hierarchy should be showing properly.

If it doesn't work for you, the first thing to check is if your code is under a 'source folder' in PyDev (i.e.: in the PYTHONPATH): See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I was having the same problem as you... but I was able to get the hierarchy view to populate for some class objects, but only partial population for other class objects. Here's an example of one that wasn't working:

[image: not working hierarchy view]

(notice the 'Parents' collection is blank despite being expanded)

Turns out the ones that were NOT working were due to me renaming some inherited class imported from some other module:

```
from module1 import ClassA as Class1
class ClassB(Class1):
    pass
```

Understandably, this was confusing pydev. Sticking with the original names resolved the issue.

[image: working hierarchy view]

(sorry the images don't line up with the snippet.. but hopefully this helps someone)